# elasticsearch 5.5 convert ip v6 to v4

Tags: elasticsearch

I used elasticsearch 5.5

I post query

```
{
"_source":["http_cliadd","http_host"],
"query": {
"bool": {
"must": [
{
"match_all": { }
}
],
"must_not": [ ],
"should": [ ]
}
},
"from": 0,
"size": 1000,
"sort": [ ],
"aggs": { }
}
```

result values

```
{
"_index": "wk_201902_3",
"_type": "http",
"_id": "2c7d11e9-be29-9719-cdba-080027553731",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"http_cliadd": "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a69:1504",
"http_host": "10.105.21.3/"
}
}


 {
"_index": "wk_201902_3",
"_type": "http",
"_id": "2c7d11e9-be29-9719-cdba-080027553731",
"_score": 1,
"_source": {
"http_cliadd": "0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a69:1504",
"http_host": "10.105.21.3/"
}
```

}

cliadd ipv6(0000:0000:0000:0000:0000:ffff:0a69:1504) ,

But i see that http_cliadd ipv4,

How to do this field?

Comment: you want convert 'ipv6' to 'ipv4'? in eleastic search query result?

Comment: yes i want convert